# segmentation fault cs50 week 2

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

I am writing a program to encrypt plain text. It forces the user to input a number in the command line, when i convert the data type of the number from string to int using atoi the program gives me segmentaion fault. I am not able to understand why.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, string argv[])
{
    //make sure the program was run by using just one command line argument

    string x = argv[1];

    if(argc !=2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    }
    else
    {
        int y = strlen( argv[1]);

        //makeing sure the command line argument input is a digit
        for( int i = 0; i < y; i++)
        {
            if( isdigit( x[i])==0)
            {
                printf( "Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            }
            return 1;
        }
    }
    printf( " hello \n");

    //convert argv[1] from string to an int
    int user_key = atoi( argv[1]);
    printf( "key = %i\n",user_key);

    //promt user for plaintext

    //for each charecter in plaintext

       // rotate charecter if it is a letter
}
```

Comment: This return statement return 1; shall be inside this if statement if( isdigit( x[i])==0)
         {
             printf( "Usage: ./caesar key\n");
         }

Comment: make sure you pass enough argument as required. Did not you pass any arg after execute file ?("./a.out" only)

Comment: @ranver dhir  Within this if statement    if(argc !=2)
   {
       printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");

   } you need to insert a return statement